# Complete family of smooth, orthogonal functions with compact support exists?

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question, wavelets

are there families of function that are:$\def\R{\mathbb R}$

1. Smooth, i.e. $C^\infty(\R\to\R)$, and
2. Complete, i.e. they can point-wise approximate<sup>*</sup> any piece-wise continuous function $\R\to\R$ almost everywhere$^1$, and
3. Are orthogonal w.r.t. to whatever product, and
4. Each function has compact support.

*) Almost everywhere. I am mostly interested in approximations of "real-world" function like used in engineering and physics, less in pathological constructs.

As far as I understand, no such families are known, so is there any reason / proof for why such families do not exist? Or is this topic of current research?

There are procedures that yield infinitely many such families, solutions of some differential operators, one example being trigonometric functions, other example is Bessel functions, other one is polynomials. However neither thereof satisfies 4.

And if you require 2., 3. and 4. then the closest you can get are [Daubechies' wavelets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daubechies_wavelet)?  They can be tailored to be $C^n$ for any finite $n$ but are not $C^\infty$.

I have no research background, but I wonder about this since I heard about Daubechies' wavelets decades ago...

Comment: One question is what precisely you mean by point 2). After all, there can be two different piecewise continuous functions $f, g : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ which nevertheless satisfy $f = g$ **almost** everywhere. You will then have $\sum_n \langle f, \varphi_n\rangle \varphi_n = \sum_n \langle g, \varphi_n\rangle \varphi_n$, so that your system can only pointwise approximate either $f$ or $g$, but not both.

Comment: @PhoemueX : Yes, always everywhere if fine like with Fourier trafo. Loosely speaking, I am mostly interested in "interesting" functions, like those that usually come up in engineering, not some pathological constructs.

Comment: Piecewise continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ need not be square integrable but Daubechies wavelets (which you later mention) are an orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. This means that the inner product with respect to which the Daubechies wavelets are orthogonal doesn't make sense on a large enough function space to talk about all piecewise continuous functions. Maybe you want to restrict the class of functions you want to approximate to piecewise continuous function that are in $L^2$ (or some other natural inner product space)?

Comment: @Rhys Steele : Assuming square-integrability for the to-be-approximized functions is fine.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some general remarks:

1. Smooth functions with compact support (denoted with $C_C^\infty(\Bbb R)$) are dense in $L^2(\Bbb R)$.
2. If $f_n\to f$ in $L^2$ sense then there is a sub-sequence $f_{n_k}$ that converges pointwise almost everywhere to $f$.
3. $L^2(\Bbb R)$ is separable.

Points 1. and 3. imply that there is some countable subset of $C_C^\infty(\Bbb R)$ that is dense in $L^2(\Bbb R)$. You can then do the Gramm-Schmidt procedure on this subset to recover an ONB of $L^2(\Bbb R)$ that consists only of $C_C^\infty$ functions.

(The Gramm-Schmidt procedure works inductively, for a sequence $v_n\neq0$ let $e_1=\frac{v_1}{\|v_1\|}$ and for $e_n$ consider first $v_n$, if it is linearly dependent on the previous $v_1,...,v_{n-1}$ throw it out, else let $e_n' = v_n - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \langle v_n, e_i\rangle e_i$ and then $e_n := \frac{e_n'}{\| e_n'\|}$.)

Now since you have an ONB $e_n$ of $C_C^\infty$ functions any $L^2$ function $f$ can be written as:
$$f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle f, e_n\rangle\, e_n$$
where the sum converges in $L^2$ sense. It follows that you then get a subsequence $N_k$ so that
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N_k} \langle f, e_n\rangle e_n$$
approximates $f$ pointwise almost everywhere by remark 2. The finite sum above is however a $C_C^\infty$ function as it is a finite linear combination of such functions.

To summarise: Yes, such families of functions exist. Given some random family of $L^2$ functions, the only thing you need in order to extract an ONB satisfying your properties are 1) closed under linear combinations and 2) dense in $L^2$. There are many such families, as these two properties are not very rare.

Comment: Two additions to this nice answer for OPs benefit:
(1) Once you have this construction, you can approximate any piecewise continuous function pointwise a.e. (not just $L^2$-ones) by a diagonal argument since if $f$ is piecewise continuous then $f \chi_{[-k,k]} \in L^2$. 
(2) It's hard to get more explicit than this construction. For example, there is no family of compact wavelets that works since it holds that if $\phi \in C^k$, $\phi(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^N c_n \phi(2x - n)$ and $\phi$ is supported in $[0,N]$ then $k \leq N-2$ (this is non-trivial but appears in works by Daubechies).

Comment: @s.harp : Your last remark indicates that such families are abundant and almost trivial to construct.  Can you give an explicit example? If it's so straight forward, why did it take so long to find Daubechies wavelets that have even less restrictive (are not $C^\infty$)?

Comment: The existence of the ONB is elementary, but the expressions that you get from this procedure may not result in an ONB that looks particularly pleasant. The "canonical" nice ONB lives on $L^2[0,1]$ and is given by functions of the form $t\mapsto e^{i2\pi n\, t}$. What breaks your back in $L^2(\Bbb R)$ is asking for both $C^\infty$ and compact support. But: Let
$$F(x):= \begin{cases} e^{-1/x^2} e^{-1/(1-x)^2} &x\in[0,1 ]\\ 0& \text{else}\end{cases}$$
this function is $C^\infty$ with support $[0,1]$. The next step is to consider $F_n(x) = e^{i2\pi n x} F(x)$. These functions are  ...

Comment: ... linearly independent and their span is dense in $L^2[0,1]$. So: Let $e_0 = F_0 / \|F_0\|$. Thats still ok, now let $\tilde e_1 = F_1 - \langle F_1, e_0\rangle e_0)$ and $e_1:= \tilde e_1/\|\tilde e_1\|$. Well now you need to calculate this scalar product. Thats not so nice anymore. Next let $\tilde e_2 = F_{-1}- \langle F_{-1}, e_1\rangle e_1 - \langle F_{-1}, e_0\rangle e_0$ and $e_2 := \tilde e_2/\|\tilde e_2\|$. And so on. This gives you an ONB of $C^\infty$ functions with compact support in $L^2(0,1)$. By translating these you can gent an ONB of all of $L^2(\Bbb R)$ ...

Comment: ... however you see the problem, calculating these coefficients is not a happy undertaking. Finding a formula for them is work. So their existence is elementary, and there are so many ONB of this form, but to find an explicit one that is "nice" for a human to handle is the difficulty, because the scalar products and norms all require evaluating some kind of integral.

Comment: (As an example, if you drop compact support then $H_n(x) e^{-x^2/2}$ is a standard orthogonal basis of $L^2(\Bbb R)$ and quite "well adapted" to human needs, here $H_n$ are the Hermite polynomials. You still need to correctly normalise this, but here the norms can be probably be read off in some table.)